# error: C2059: syntax error : '{'

Tags: c++, syntax-error

I would like to run an application in qt creator. But when i click on build, it showing error in carddetect.cpp

The error occurs here: `void CardDetect::aamvaIssuerList()`

But I can't find out what that error is.

```
124: error: C2059: syntax error : '{'
124: error: C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
124: error: C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
```

This is my code:

```
#include "carddetect.h"
#include <QDebug>

void CardDetect::aamvaIssuerList(){
        issuerList [ "636026" ] =  (struct issuer) {"Arizona", "AZ", "L"};
        issuerList [ "0636021"] =  (struct issuer) { "Arkansas", "AR", "" };
        issuerList [ "636014" ] =  (struct issuer) { "California", "CA", "L" };
        issuerList [ "636020" ] =  (struct issuer) { "Colorado", "CO", "NN-NNN-NNNN" };
        issuerList [ "636010" ] =  (struct issuer) { "Florida", "FL", "LNNN-NNN-NN-NNN-N" };
        issuerList [ "636018" ] =  (struct issuer) { "Iowa", "IA", "NNNLLNNNN" };
    }
```

and carddetect.h is

```
#ifndef CARDDETECT_H
#define CARDDETECT_H

#include <QMap>
#include "magcard.h"

struct issuer {
    QString name;
    QString abbreviation;
    QString format;
};

class CardDetect {
    public:
        CardDetect( MagCard *_card = 0 );
        void setCard( MagCard *_card ); 

    private:
        MagCard *card;

        void processCard();

        void luhnCheck();
        void creditCardCheck();
        void aamvaCardCheck( QString expDate );
        void aamvaIssuerList();
        QMap<QString,struct issuer> issuerList;

};


#endif // CARDDETECT_H
```

That code working @keltar

but now in this function

```
void CardDetect::aamvaCardCheck( QString expDate ) {
    if( card->encoding == IATA )
        return; //we're only going to support ABA for now
    struct issuer issuerInfo;

QString iin = card->accountNumber.left( 6 );

issuerInfo = issuerList.value( iin );
if( issuerInfo.name.isEmpty() ) {
    iin = card->accountNumber.mid( 1, 6 );
    issuerInfo = issuerList.value( iin );
    if( issuerInfo.name.isEmpty() )
        return; // this is not a known AAMVA card, abort
}
```

It showing error

```
error: C2512: 'issuer' : no appropriate default constructor available
error: C2512: 'issuer::issuer' : no appropriate default constructor available
```

in struct issuer issuerInfo;

Comment: It is meaningless to tag this question with **both** C and C++, because it means something different in C and C++. In C(99), this is valid code, in C++, it is not. So, which language are you using?

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant You seem confused. This is clearly C++ and not C.

Comment: The construction you're using (`(type){initialiser}`) is a compound literal; it is C11, or any GNU C/C++, but as far as I'm aware it isn't standard C++ and MSVC don't support it. Rewrite your code.

Comment: OK thank you.i am a beginner in c++.will you please help me to change that @keltar

Comment: @DavidHeffernan No, I'm not confused – just look at the revision history of the question. I've written my comment when it contained only the first code snippet (the one with the C99 compound literals). There was no valid C++ in the question yet. Now it's obvious that OP meant it to be C++, but unfortunately it still isn't.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant The presence of `void CardDetect::aamvaIssuerList()` in that revision points to C++. The mention of Qt also. I don't particularly want to argue though. Yes, the funky initializer is not standard C++ it seems. But compilers often have support for extensions. I still cannot understand why the compiler objects though.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Oh heck, I read the question that the error was on this line: `void CardDetect::aamvaIssuerList(){` But it is not. It is indeed the compound literals. Gah!!

Comment: @Aishu well I can't predict all cases you use. Add the default constructor too (`issuer() {}` inside structure).

Comment: i am sorry..that also working.thank you @keltar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot use compound literals, here is an example of how it could be done:

Add constructor to your structure:

```
struct issuer {
    issuer(const char *nm, const char *abbr, const char *fmt) : name(nm),
         abbreviation(abbr), format(fmt) {}

    QString name;
    QString abbreviation;
    QString format;
};
```

And change your function to:

```
void CardDetect::aamvaIssuerList(){
    issuerList [ "636026" ] =  issuer("Arizona", "AZ", "L");
    // same for the rest of the lines
}
```

There are other ways to do the same, of course.